# c# script waiting in terminal but exiting directly as a daemon

Tags: c#, linux, mono, daemon, systemd

I have a C# script I modified. I want to run it at startup using a daemon and systemctl (the original is this [NZXT automatic fan controller script](https://github.com/quido3/LinuxGrid-v2Controller)). The code created a repeating timer to execute a piece of code every 4 seconds and blocks exiting the script using `Console.ReadLine();`. I compiled and tested the script using msc and mono. It works as intended in a terminal (it is *not* exiting directly).

However, when run as a daemon, `Console.ReadLine();` doesn't wait and the script directly completes the main method and exits.

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Timers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{

    private static string root;
    private static string confFile = "/home/mohammadah/scripts/grid+v2/conf.d";
    private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

    private static int maxSpeed = 100;
    private static int minSpeed = 35;
    // do not change this. all fan speeds have to rounded to the nearest multiple of 5
    private static int minimumRound = 5;
    private static int timerTime = 4000;
    private static int defaultFanSpeed = 40;

    // fans: 
    // 1: empty
    // 2: empty
    // 3: bottom
    // 4: top
    // 5: CPU
    // 6: Back
    private static int[] gpuFans;
    private static int gpuMaxTemp;
    private static int gpuMinTemp;

    private static int[] cpuFans;
    private static int cpuMaxTemp;
    private static int cpuMinTemp;

    private static float lastCPUSpeed = 0;
    private static float lastGPUSpeed = 0;

    public static void Main()
    {
    //    Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath));
       ParseConfigFile(confFile);


        if(!Regex.IsMatch(DoGridCommand("get fan 1"), @"Fan 1: \d{1,5} RPM")){
            DoGridCommand("init");
        }

        DoGridCommand("set fans all speed " + defaultFanSpeed);

        

        SetTimer();
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress the Enter key to exit the application...\n");
        // Process.GetCurrentProcess().WaitForExit();

        Console.ReadLine();
        aTimer.Stop();
        aTimer.Dispose();
        Console.WriteLine("Terminating the application...");
    }

    private static float GetGPUTemp(){
        ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("/bin/bash", "-c nvidia-smi -q -d temperature");
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
        proc.Start();
        string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        
        char first = '-';
        char second = '-';
        string temp = "";

        foreach (char c in result)
        {
            if(c=='1' || c == '2'|| c == '3'|| c == '4'|| c == '5'|| c == '6'|| c == '7'|| c == '8'|| c == '9'|| c == '0'|| c == 'C'){
                if(first == '-'){
                    first = c;
                }else if(second == '-'){
                    second = c;
                }else if(c == 'C'){
                    temp = "" + first + second;
                    break;
                }
            }else{
                first = '-';
                second = '-';
            }
        }
        return float.Parse(temp);
    }

    private static int GetCPUTemp(){

        string tempLineStart = "Packageid0:+";

        ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("/bin/bash", "-c sensors");
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
        proc.Start();

        int temp = 0;
        string line = "";
        while ((line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine()) != null) {
            line = Regex.Replace(line, @"\s+", "");
            if(Regex.IsMatch(line, tempLineStart)){
                line = line.Trim().Replace(tempLineStart.Trim(), "");
                line = line.Substring(0, 6);
                line = Regex.Replace(line, "[^0-9.]", "");
                float t = float.Parse(line);
                temp = (int)t;
                break;
            }
        }

        return temp;
    }

    private static void SetTimer()
    {
        // Create a timer with a two second interval.
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(timerTime);
        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
        aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        aTimer.AutoReset = true;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }    

    private static void ParseConfigFile(string fileName){
        string gridfanLocation = "GridfanLocation:";
        string gpuFanLineStart = "GPUFans:";
        string gpuMaxLineStart = "GPUMaxTemp:";
        string gpuMinLineStart = "GPUMinTemp:";
        string cpuFanLineStart = "CPUFans:";
        string cpuMinLineStart = "CPUMinTemp:";
        string cpuMaxLineStart = "CPUMaxTemp:";
    
        StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(fileName);
        string line;    
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {

            line = line.Trim();
            // Regex.Replace(line, @"\s+", "");
            // ignore commented out (starts with "//") or empty lines
            if(line.StartsWith("//") || line.Equals("")) continue;
            // set gpu temp at which gpu fans will be set at 100% speed
            else if(Regex.IsMatch(line, gridfanLocation)){
                root = line.Trim().Replace(gridfanLocation, "");
            // set gpu fan list using the numbering found on gridfan git repo
            }else if(Regex.IsMatch(line, gpuFanLineStart)){
                line = line.Trim().Replace(gpuFanLineStart, "");
                string[] fans = line.Split(",");
                gpuFans = new int[fans.Length];
                for (int i =0;i<fans.Length;i++){
                    gpuFans[i] = int.Parse(fans[i].Trim());
                }
            // set gpu temp at which gpu fans will be set at 100% speed
            } else if(Regex.IsMatch(line, gpuMaxLineStart)){
                line = line.Trim().Replace(gpuMaxLineStart, "");
                gpuMaxTemp = int.Parse(line);
            // set gpu temp at which gpu fans will be set at lowest speed
            } else if(Regex.IsMatch(line, gpuMinLineStart)){
                line = line.Trim().Replace(gpuMinLineStart, "");
                gpuMinTemp = int.Parse(line);
            // set cpu fan list using the numbering found on gridfan git repo
            } else if(Regex.IsMatch(line, cpuFanLineStart)){
                line = line.Trim().Replace(cpuFanLineStart, "");
                string[] fans = line.Split(",");
                cpuFans = new int[fans.Length];
                for (int i =0;i<fans.Length;i++){
                    cpuFans[i] = int.Parse(fans[i].Trim());
                }
            // set cpu temp at which gpu fans will be set at 100% speed
            } else if(Regex.IsMatch(line, cpuMaxLineStart)){
                line = line.Trim().Replace(cpuMaxLineStart, "");
                cpuMaxTemp = int.Parse(line);
            // set cpu temp at which gpu fans will be set at lowest speed
            } else if(Regex.IsMatch(line, cpuMinLineStart)){
                line = line.Trim().Replace(cpuMinLineStart, "");
                cpuMinTemp = int.Parse(line);
            }
            else throw new Exception ("Something went wrong while parsing config file \"./conf.d\"");
        }
    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("====================================================");
        float gpuTemp = GetGPUTemp();
        Console.WriteLine("Graphics (GPU) temp: " + gpuTemp+"`C");
        float gpuPercentage = 100 * ((gpuTemp - gpuMinTemp) / (gpuMaxTemp - gpuMinTemp));
        Console.WriteLine("Graphics (GPU) percentage: " + gpuPercentage+"`%");
        float gpuFanSpeed = gpuPercentage > maxSpeed ? maxSpeed : gpuPercentage < minSpeed ? minSpeed : gpuPercentage;
        gpuFanSpeed = (int) Math.Ceiling(gpuFanSpeed / minimumRound) * minimumRound;

        if(lastGPUSpeed != gpuFanSpeed){
            if(!Regex.IsMatch(DoGridCommand("get fan 1"), @"Fan 1: \d{1,5} RPM")){
                DoGridCommand("init");
            }
            foreach (int gpuFan in gpuFans){
                DoGridCommand("set fans " + gpuFan + " speed " + gpuFanSpeed);
            }
        }
        float cpuTemp = GetCPUTemp();
        Console.WriteLine("Central (CPU) temp: " + cpuTemp+"`C");
        float cpuPercentage = 100 * ((cpuTemp - cpuMinTemp) / (cpuMaxTemp - cpuMinTemp));
        Console.WriteLine("Central (CPU) percentage: " + cpuPercentage+"`%");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        float cpuFanSpeed = (cpuPercentage > maxSpeed ? maxSpeed : cpuPercentage < minSpeed ? minSpeed : cpuPercentage);
        cpuFanSpeed = (int) Math.Ceiling(cpuFanSpeed / minimumRound) * minimumRound;

        if(lastCPUSpeed != gpuFanSpeed){
            if(!Regex.IsMatch(DoGridCommand("get fan 1"), @"Fan 1: \d{1,5} RPM")){
                DoGridCommand("init");
            }

            foreach (int cpuFan in cpuFans){
                DoGridCommand("set fans " + cpuFan + " speed " + cpuFanSpeed);
            }
        }
        lastCPUSpeed = cpuFanSpeed;
        lastGPUSpeed = gpuFanSpeed;
        Console.WriteLine("====================================================");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    private static string DoGridCommand(string command){
        ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("/bin/bash", root + "/gridfan " + command);
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
        proc.Start();
        string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine("Command result: " + result.Trim());
        // System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        return result;
    }
}
```

conf.d used in main code (not really important, but for completeness):

```
// gridFan repo = https://github.com/CapitalF/gridfan
// root of gridFan script location
GridfanLocation:/home/mohammadah/scripts/grid+v2
// GPU fans id/ports as per the schema in gridFan repo readme
GPUFans: 3
// GPU temp at which GPU fans will be set at 100% speed
GPUMaxTemp: 75
// GPU temp at which GPU fans will be set at lowest speed
GPUMinTemp: 35
// GPU fans id/port as per the schema in gridFan repo readme
CPUFans: 4, 5, 6
// CPU temp at which CPU fans will be set at 100% speed
CPUMaxTemp: 75
// CPU temp at which CPU fans will be set at lowest speed
CPUMinTemp: 35
```

daemon .service file

```
[Unit]
Description=Grid+ v2 automatic fan controller

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mono /home/mohammadah/scripts/grid+v2/LinuxGrid-v2Controller.exe
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Unsure here, never started C# program as a linux Daemon, but could it be that there is no `Console.ReadLine` available when run as a daemon? In this case you would need another strategy to "wait" for some message form the OS / user

Comment: Services are intended to run without user interaction, so are daemons. Pretty much identical as a windows service, you should consider adapting your program to avoid the `Console` commands. I would suggest and infinite loop `while(true) { }`.

Comment: Unrelated note: I would suggest changing your `c=='1' || c == '2'|| c == '3'...` with [Char.IsNumber()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isnumber?view=netcore-3.1). Shorter code and easier to read/understand